# Trying to run gevent socketio example (Django)

Tags: python, django, sockets, gevent

I have encountered the following error:

```
(virtenv3)iMac:codysoyland-django-socketio-example-d35672f admin$ python run_example.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "run_example.py", line 12, in <module>
    from socketio import SocketIOServer
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.6-universal/egg/socketio/__init__.py", line 7, in <module>

  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.6-universal/egg/socketio/server.py", line 4, in <module>
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.6-universal/egg/gevent/__init__.py", line 41, in <module>

  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.6-universal/egg/gevent/core.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.6-universal/egg/gevent/core.py", line 6, in __bootstrap__
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/admin/.python-eggs/gevent-0.13.6-py2.6-macosx-10.6-universal.egg-tmp/gevent/core.so, 2): Symbol not found: _event_global_current_base_
  Referenced from: /Users/admin/.python-eggs/gevent-0.13.6-py2.6-macosx-10.6-universal.egg-tmp/gevent/core.so
  Expected in: flat namespace
 in /Users/admin/.python-eggs/gevent-0.13.6-py2.6-macosx-10.6-universal.egg-tmp/gevent/core.so
```

What is this error telling me? I installed all the example's dependencies without errors.

`greenlet`, `cython`, `libevent`, `gevent`, `gevent-socketio`, `gevent-webstocket` with no problems there

Answer (score 0):

Did you compile libevent with llvm? I think the homebrew formula (before it switched to libevent2) had a "don't compile with llvm" directive because of this error.

Comment: Also, fwiw this error would occur with a simple gevent example, don't need to invoke the socket.io stuff. Additionally #gevent on freenode would have people willing to help debug I bet.